# Custom slider not quite working

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with a slider I have made, I need it so that when the next div comes onscreen that is at the top of the div, so it looks smooth, if you look at my jsfiddle you will see that it comes in at the bottom then skips to the top... http://jsfiddle.net/Gfzwp/

If you could help me that would be great, thanks!

**html**

```
    <div class="section">
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="next"><span class="hidden">Next</span></div>
        </div>
         <div class="gallery" id="one">
            <div class="box">one</div>
            <div class="box">two</div>
            <div class="box">three</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery" id="two">
            <div class="box">one</div>
            <div class="box">two</div>
            <div class="box">three</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
    .section {
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

    .gallery {
        width:100%;
        min-height:450px;
        display:inline-block;
        top:0;
        white-space:normal;
        float:left;
        padding:0px 0px 200px 49px;
    }

    .box {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background:#ff0000;
        float:left;
        margin:0px 3px 3px 0px;    
    }

    .controls {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:3;
    }

    .controls .next {
        width:44px;
        height:133px;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 2px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

jQuery    
​$('.controls .next').click(function(){
    $('.gallery#one').hide('slide', { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    $('.gallery#two').show('slide', { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});    ​
```

Comment: As per guidelines for this site, you should provide the appropriate code snippets even though you have a fiddle. You have to imagine that the question would still work and be solvable if jsfiddle.net suddenly vanished.

Comment: Ah sorry, I've added in code snippets. Usually when I provide them I get asked for a jsfiddle, I shall provide both in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:absolute` to the gallery CSS.

Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/Gfzwp/5/

Comment: I can't add position:absolute without defining a height to the gallery div and I don't want to define a height because I want the boxes to move under each other as the browser is scaled.